# Why is disk I/O faster in a virtual machine than on the native operating system?

Tags: python, virtual-machine, vmware-player

```
#This program reads and writes 1k data to the same files 10000.
import threading
import time

def read_write_file(thread_num):
    wf_name= "w_" + str(thread_num) + ".txt"
    for i in range(0,10000):
        try:
            fd= open("1k.txt","r+")
            w_fd= open(wf_name,"wb")
            str1= fd.read(1024)
            w_fd.write(str1)
            fd.close()
        except:
            print "Error: I/O Exception"
def threads_start(num):
    threads=dict() 
    try:
        for index in range(num):
            threads[index]= threading.Thread(target=read_write_file,args=(index,))
            threads[index].start()
        for i in range(0,4):
            threads[i].join()
    except:
        print "Error: problem in running threads"

start_time= time.time()
threads_start(4)
print time.time() - start_time, " Seconds"
```

The above code is running faster in virtual machine than in native system. According to my understanding it should be slower than native system because of the overhead. Why is it faster?

Comment: Typically this means your virtualization technology is cheating on its caching semantics -- ie. persisting changes to memory, but telling the guest that they're persisted to disk.

Comment: Overbearing anti-virus software on the host can be extremely expensive on the creation of lots of little files (it has to do a check on each one). Whereas a VM typically stores data in one big already-existing file of a type the virus checker doesn't care about.

Comment: Is the virtual machine running the same OS and version of Python? If it isn't, the comparison is fairly irrelevant.

Comment: It's directly related to I/O scheduler. The VM's scheduler just passes it down to the next layer while the native O/S' scheduler has to grind for the I/O.

Comment: Check these 2 out https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/12/06/use-elevator-noop-for-linux-virtual-machines/ https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5427